# HTML code working fine in firefox 11.0 but not in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html

The following code works as per my requirement in firefox. but coming to IE 8, except file browsing nothing happening. Can any one check it out for issues pls?any thing need to add in the first line? 
 thanks in advance.

the code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadfile(input) {
var theRange = null; 
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
document.getElementById('mytext').value = e.target.result;
var msg = e.target.result;
}
reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check1() 
{

var str = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
var names=document.getElementById('username').value ;

var n = str.search(names);
if(n==-1)
    {
        alert("not found");
    }   
else 
{
    alert("user name found");
    var str1 = document.getElementById('mytext').value;

    var str_array = str1.split(',');



    var ind = str_array.indexOf(names);
    //alert("I worked");
    var kname = str_array[ind];
alert(kname);
    var i=0;


    for (i = ind; i< ind+8; i++ )
    {
    k=0;
    }

    var print = str_array[i];

    var print_array = print.split('\n');
    alert(print_array[0]);
}
}   

</script>
</head>

<body>
Select the file to display:
<input type="file" onchange="loadfile(this)">
<br></br>
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="mytext"></textarea>
<br></br>
<form> Enter UserName: <input type="text" id="username" name="username"> <b></form>
<br></br>
<input type="button" onclick="check1();" value="Search" /> 
 <pre id="output"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What kind of place mandates Firefox _11_ support? We're up to 25 now, folks! Anyway `FileReader` is not supported in IE8.

Comment: Please add a working copy in jsfiddle ... ?

Comment: I did think that is the oddest browser requirement I've heard of!

Comment: What adjectly your codes doing..

Comment: @Coder A working fiddle will be a bit tricky if IE8 doesn't support FileReader anyway.

Comment: @Mike ohh.. I was not knowint that.. thanks for information... (y)

Comment: @Qantas thanks for ur answer. any more functions in the code that wont work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not have support for FileReader.

A great site to find out if a browser supports certain features or not is http://caniuse.com/
In your case you could've searched for: http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader